# Responsive background image - bootstrap jumbotron with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for quite sometime and at this point feel that I am wasting it by not presenting my current situation. I am trying to create a landing page for a website with a responsive background image. I am not having issues with the responsiveness of the width of the image. It will stretch and respond to the scaling of the web browser. However, I cannot get it to fit the height of the web browser. In fact, it only goes about 1 inch down from the top of the browser and no further. I have looked at MANY solutions but most suggest things I have already done. As a side not, I am trying to do this using `Rails`. I have created a `root static-page#home` and am working inside the static-page folder in `home.html.erb` and the `static_pages.css.scss`. Here is my code:

home.html.erb:

```
<div class="jumbotron debug">
 <div class="container">
 </div>
</div>
```

static_pages.css.scss:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url(http://www.wolmer.lt/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/tree-of-light-daughter.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Now the `background-size: 100% 100%;` should be the line that initially scales the image to 100% height and 100% width if i'm not mistaken. I am still having no such luck with it. I have even tried to set `html` and `body` tag to `height: 100%` and that did nothing. Maybe I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One thing I have tried that is a fix.. but not necessarily a solution. I have set the `background-size` to `cover` and given my image a set height. This can work but it defeats the purpose as the height is not responsive. All in all, the main issue is I just cannot set the height of the `jumbotron` class to 100%. Setting `html, body { height: 100%; }` does not seem to help either.

Comment: Have you checked what the height of the `body` and `html` elements are?  Sometimes those have a height of `0`.  Try adding `html,body{height:100%}` to your css.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the container itself is empty.  It's happy to provide a background image to fill the space, but the space in this case is empty.

So , to fix it, make sure the page height is always the height of the browser.

```
# css style
html,body { height: 100%; }

.jumbotron {
  background: url(http://www.wolmer.lt/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/tree-of-light-daughter.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to actually find out why setting the `jumbotron` height to 100% wasn't working and why setting `html, body { height: 100%; }` wasn't working. The problem was that html and body weren't 100%, so when I set the `jumbotron` class to 100% height, it would only fill in 100% of what the html/body were at. When setting html/body to 100% height it would increase the height to the window size, but the `jumbotron` class would stay at it's normal height of 96px(which came because of the `container` div inside of the `jumbotron` div. So when I set `jumbotron` class to height of 100% AND html/body it worked.

That may or may not make sense, but that was the solution to my problem. Thank you for those who helped in anyway.